# angular 2: combining *ngIf and *ngFor executes loop with a last undefined item

Tags: angular, angular2-template

http://plnkr.co/edit/ihdAJuUcyOj5Ze93BwIQ?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let v of myValues;">
        This is my value: {{v}}
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div *ngIf="show" *ngFor="let v of myValues;">
        This is my value: {{v}}
      </div>


  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public user: User = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
      address1: '11, High Street',
      postcode: '1234'
    }
  }

  myValues = ['one','two','three'];
  show = true;


  public save(form: IUser, isValid: boolean) {
    console.log(form, isValid);
  }
}

export interface User {
  name: string;
  address?: {
    address1?: string;
    postcode?: string;
  }
}
```

As it can be seen in this plunkr, the second *ngFor will be executed one too many times.

Now is this a bug? Or am I just forbidden from using *ngFor and *ngIf together? I could not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same element are not supported.
As workaround you can use:

**update (2.0.0)**

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="show">
    <div *ngFor="let v of myValues;">
      This is my value: {{v}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

**original**

```
  <template [ngIf]="show">
    <div *ngFor="let v of myValues;">
      This is my value: {{v}}
    </div>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this

```
<template let-v ngFor [ngForOf]="myValues">
        <div *ngIf="show">
          This is my value: {{v}}
        </div>
</template>
```